# Searchkick highlight: undefined method `with_details' for []:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am trying to implement the excerpt highlighting into my app using SearchKick, but Rails keep telling me that I am getting the wrong object type.

My controller:

```
def search

  @articles = Article.text_search(params[:q])
  ...
```

My view:

```
- articles.with_details.each do |article, details|
  ...
  p.mb-15.excerpt
    = details[:highlight][:content]
```

My model:

```
searchkick highlight: [:content]

def self.text_search(query)
  if query.present?
    search(
           query,
           fields:
              [
               "title^10",
               "h1^5",
               "meta_description",
               "content"
              ],
           limit: 5,
           highlight: {
           fields: {content:
               {fragment_size: 100}
             }
           }
       )
  else
    []
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are getting `[]` as your text_search result from this else branch in your model:

```
else
  []
end
```

So maybe you can do something like this in your view and controller to escape such an error:

**Controller:**

```
articles = Article.text_search(params[:q])
@detailed_articles = articles.empty? ? [] : articles.with_details
```

**View:**

```
- @detailed_articles.each do |article, details|
  ...
  p.mb-15.excerpt
    = details[:highlight][:content]
```